# "14 days availability" OpenMapTiles.com data

Tags: openmaptiles

my name's Diego.
I'm a passionate 3D drawer, and i'm about to starting a nice project which needed some satellite and hillshading images from a region of the France.
I've seen that in https://openmaptiles.com/ you can choose to buy a one-time data of a specific area, and i've bought both the satellite and hillshading data for the region i needed.
In my page, where i can download the data, it shows a phrase: 
"List of created dataset. These extracts are available for 14 days."
What it means? i can't use what i've bought for over 14 days? or just the link disappear? because my project it lasts over 14 days, i thought if i bought data it can be used offline forever (ofc not updated).
Someone can explain this?
thank you in advance,
have a nice day!
Diego

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the purchase from OpenMapTiles.com!

The download link for the extract expires and the extract is deleted from our servers in 14 days after the purchase. You can download the extract anytime during these 14 days. Unfortunately, the extracts cannot remain on our servers as we would run out of the storage capacity quickly.

In case this wouldn't be suitable for you, you can subscribe to one of the production packages available at https://openmaptiles.com/production-package/. This way, all the data for the whole planet would be available for you anytime.

Have a nice day as well and we wish you good luck with your project!